# Rails locale development server "rails s" to serve multiple request at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Windows 7, Rails 3 here. I local/development mode, `rails server` does not handle multiple request at the same time. The process crash and the cmd prompt comes in front.

I've noticed this behaviour when :

- having too much ajax request, too close from one another
- loading a simple page on 2 browsers

Is there a way workaround that ? Change the local server (default is webrick) ? How is that done ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading this simple page? What does your page's view and controller code look like?

Comment: In development mode, by default, the mongrel server run in single threaded mode. You can add config.threadsafe! in development.rb to make it run in multi-threaded mode.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this still needs an answer but I did this by adding `gem 'puma'` to the Gemfile then you'll need to add `config.threadsafe!` to either your `config/application.rb` or the environment file you're running on (like `config/environments/development.rb`.

Sometimes you might not want threadsafe on so I so did this in my `development.rb`:

```
if ENV["THREADS"]
  config.threadsafe!
end
```

Now (with what I did in my `development.rb`) I can do `rails s Puma` and it will run with a max of 16 threads and can handle multiple requests. You can also up the thread pool and configure more with Puma, docs are [here](https://github.com/puma/puma)

### Update

Note that the use of `config.threadsafe!` is not needed in Rails 4+ and is deprecated I believe.

Comment: Webrick can also serve mutliple requests, so it's not necessary to replace it with Puma.

Comment: Indeed, though seem to avoid using WEBrick in production and if you do choose to go with Puma for production, this brings your development environment a little closer to your production configuration. You're right though, that's not the discussion at hand, I didn't know that at the time of writing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the mongrel gem and this specify which server you want to use when you `rails s`

I don't know how you guys do it on win systems. Why not run a virtual Unix box? isn't rails just much easier with it? So with Unix it would be something like:

Install mongrel gem:

```
gem install mongrel
```

Then specify which server you want to run:

```
rails server mongrel
```